# how to get last known contiguous value in postgres ltree field?

Tags: postgresql, contiguous, ltree

I have a child table called wbs_numbers. the primary key `id` is a [ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html)

A typical example is

| id | series_id |
| --- | --- |
| abc.xyz.00001 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00002 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00003 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00101 | 1 |

so the parent table called series. it has a field called `last_contigous_max`.

given the above example, i want the series of id 1 to have its last contigous max be 3

can always assume that the ltree of wbs is always 3 fragment separated by dot. and the last fragment is always a 5 digit numeric string left padded by zero. can always assume the first child is always ending with `00001` and the theoretical total children of a series will never exceed 9999.

If you think of it as gaps and islands, the wbs_numbers will never start with a gap **within a series**. it will always start with an island.

meaning to say this is not possible.

| id | series_id |
| --- | --- |
| abc.xyz.00010 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00011 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00012 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00101 | 1 |

This is possible

| id | series_id |
| --- | --- |
| abc.xyz.00001 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00004 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00005 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00051 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00052 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.00100 | 1 |
| abc.xyz.10001 | 2 |
| abc.xyz.10002 | 2 |
| abc.xyz.10003 | 2 |
| abc.xyz.10051 | 2 |
| abc.xyz.10052 | 2 |
| abc.xyz.10100 | 2 |
| abc.xyz.20001 | 3 |
| abc.xyz.20002 | 3 |
| abc.xyz.20003 | 3 |
| abc.xyz.20004 | 3 |
| abc.xyz.20052 | 3 |
| abc.xyz.20100 | 3 |

so the last max contiguous in this case is

- for series id 1 => 1
- for series id 2 => 3
- for series id 3 => 4

What's the query to calculate the `last_contigous_max` number for any given series_id?

I also don't mind having another table just to store "islands".

Also, you can safely assume that wbs_number records will never be deleted once created. The `id` in the `wbs_numbers` table will never be altered once filled in as well.

Meaning to say islands will only grow and never shrink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can carry out your problem following these steps:

- extract your integer value from your "*id*" field
- compute a ranking value sided with your id value
- filter out when your ranking value does not match your id value
- get tied last row for each of your matches

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CAST(RIGHT(id_, 4) AS INTEGER)  AS idval
    FROM tab
), ranked AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY series_id ORDER BY idval) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT series_id, idval
FROM ranked
WHERE idval = rn
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY series_id ORDER BY idval DESC)
FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iQspHRuYCPSvVYAffzUThc/0).